# MySQL combine columns into rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have run a SUM query to achieve the following 2 columns and rows:

```
sum1 | sum2
10     20
```

The query I ran was the following:

```
SELECT SUM(minutes) as "sum1", SUM(hoursWorked) AS "sum2"
FROM  entries
JOIN  employees on employeeID = employees.userID 
WHERE YEARWEEK(dateCreated) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
ORDER BY employeeID;
```

I want to combine the values into one column, to get the following:

```
sums
10
20
```

A bit lost on how to start with this. Searching has resulting in Concat which obviously wont work.

Can anyone help suggest a method to do this, or the correct function I should be searching for?

**EDIT:** As suggestions below, I resolved this by doing the following:

```
SELECT SUM(minutes) as "sum1"
FROM   entries
JOIN   employees on employeeID = employees.userID 
WHERE  YEARWEEK(dateCreated) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
UNION
SELECT SUM(hoursWorked) AS "sum2"
FROM   entries
JOIN   employees on employeeID = employees.userID 
WHERE  YEARWEEK(dateCreated) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UNION ALL method :

```
SELECT sum1 Sums 
FROM your_tablename   
UNION ALL
SELECT sum2 Sums
FROM your_tablename
```

Comment: thanks! I have already run a query to return sum1 and sum2, from two tables. Can I use UNION ALL in the same query?

Comment: @JimDover,Yes it is possible UNION ALL in query.which table contain minutes & which table  contain hoursWorked

Comment: Thanks!!! I resolved this - I edited my post with the solution also. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is UNION operation might help you.

Please take a look at this resource : [W3SCHOOLS_UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)